# Can I define nested mutually dependent types in Coq?

Tags: dependent-type, coq

I am trying to model the following in Coq, which works fine in Haskell (below is Haskell code):

```
data Point = Pt Config Config 
data Line = Ln Point Point | Ext Line 
data Circle = Crc Point Line
data Figure = P Point | L Line | C Circle
type Config = [Figure]


a = Pt [] []
b = Pt [] [P a]
ln = Ln a b
d = Pt [L ln] [P a, P b]
```

Basically, *b* is a distinct point from *a*, *ln* is the straight line going through *a* and *b*, and *d* is a point on line *ln* but distinct from *a* and from *b*.
The problem is that Config depends on Point, Line and Circle, and then Point depends on Config. I have seen that mutually dependent types existed in Coq, but do they work after multiple levels of nesting or indirection like this?

If not, do you know another proof-assistant which allows such constructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do mutually defined inductive types in Coq with [the «with» syntax](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/inductive.html#mutually-defined-inductive-types)

You end up with this definition:

```
Inductive Point : Type :=
  | Pt : Config -> Config -> Point
with Line : Type :=
  | Ln : Point -> Point -> Line
  | Ext : Line -> Line
with Circle : Type :=
  | Crc : Point -> Line -> Circle
with Figure : Type :=
  | P : Point -> Figure
  | L : Line -> Figure
  | C : Circle -> Figure
with Config : Type :=
  | Conf : list Figure -> Config.
```

Here, I did make Config an inductive type (i.e. with a constructor) but you can also make it a *notation* for `list Figure` like this:

```
Inductive Point : Type :=
  | Pt : list Figure -> list Figure -> Point
with Line : Type :=
  | Ln : Point -> Point -> Line
  | Ext : Line -> Line
with Circle : Type :=
  | Crc : Point -> Line -> Circle
with Figure : Type :=
  | P : Point -> Figure
  | L : Line -> Figure
  | C : Circle -> Figure.
Definition Config := list Figure.
```

You can then translate your code sample to Coq Syntax:

```
Definition a := Pt (Conf nil) (Conf nil).
Definition b := Pt (Conf nil) (Conf (cons (P a) nil)).
Definition ln := Ln a b.
Definition d := Pt (Conf (cons (L ln) nil)) (Conf (cons (P b) (cons (P a) nil))).
```

With the second *definition* solution, the code is simpler to use :

```
Definition a := Pt nil nil.
Definition b := Pt nil (cons (P a) nil).
Definition ln := Ln a b.
Definition d := Pt (cons (L ln) nil) (cons (P b) (cons (P a) nil)).
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that is awesome.